# dgps commands return such as: "bash: cgps: command not found", apparently because they are not on $PATH

Tags: pi-3b+

Installed dgps on RPi 3 B, connected Sparkfun f9T RTK GPS board, and received NMEA stream via SSH serial port. So the setup works. However all the dgps commands return command not found. Looking at former answers the problem may be not having them in `$PATH`. Please help how to get them on.

Comment: Is this question about modifying your `PATH`? And what is a SSH serial port?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange. If you haven't already, please take a few minutes to take the ["tour"](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour), and read through some of the ["Help topics"](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help); in particular, ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). I've studied your question for a few minutes, even tried to look up the hardware item you referenced, but I came up blank! I think you will get better results if you invest a little more time in your question. Please try to do that.